# XUbuntu 13.04 can't delete icons from desktop

Tags: 13.04, xfce

Today I installed Xubuntu session in Ubuntu 13.04, but I noticed I can't delete any icons from desktop, when I try to delete one of them I get this error (translated from my language): This feature requires the presence service file manager (as provided by Thunar).

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command, press `[Alt]`+`[F2]` then enter this:
`thunar --daemon`
that should have been running once you logged in, check your startup-applications